# Arduino UNO and SPI eeprom (AT93C46D)

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, eeprom

I'm trying to write to and read from an AT93C46D eeprom using an Arduino UNO but for some reason the output I'm getting is not what I expect.

The eeprom has a data structure of 128 words of 8 bits each and I'm trying to write 10000010 to each word. When reading back the data however I get 11000001.
When I write 00000000 to all words I get 10000000 for all words when reading. I tested my code on 2 AT93C46D eeproms and both gave the same result.

It looks like the MSB is always 1 (when reading) for some reason.

I'm probably making a stupid mistake but I can't seem to find it, any help is greatly appreciated!

Datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-5193-seeprom-at93c46d-datasheet.pdf

```
#include<SPI.h>
#define DATAOUT 11//MOSI
#define DATAIN  12//MISO 
#define SPICLOCK  13//sck
#define SS 10//ss


void setup()
{
  pinMode(SS,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATAOUT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATAIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(SPICLOCK,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

  fill();

  dump();
}

void loop()
{

}

void fill()
{
  Serial.println("Send EWEN opcode");
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
  SPI.transfer(B10011); //EWEN
  SPI.transfer(B0000000);
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW);

  delay(100);

  for (int i=0; i < 128; i++) {
    digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
    SPI.transfer(B101);
    SPI.transfer(i);
    SPI.transfer(B10000010);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(SS,LOW);
  }

  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Send EWDS opcode");
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
  SPI.transfer(B1000); //EWDS
  SPI.transfer(B00000000);
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW);

  delay(10);
}

void dump(){
  Serial.println("Dumping AT93C46D");

  byte b;

  for (int i=0; i < 128; i++) {
    digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
    SPI.transfer(B110); //read opcode
    SPI.transfer(i);
    b = SPI.transfer(B00000000); //clock data out
    digitalWrite(SS,LOW);
    Serial.println(b, BIN);
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not look like an SPI device (or at least 8-bit aligned). Might need to bit-bang that device.

Comment: `B10011`? Don't you mean `B10011000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the product spec again I think it might be possible to get this working. The protocol is MSB with a start bit S followed by two bit op-code, and parameters. SPI on AVR is 8-bit transfer but transfer can be byte aligned with the start bit.

READ is op-code(10) followed by 7-bit address, a dummy bit and the read value. That is in total 11+8-bits. Mapping that to 8-bit transfer would be:

```
spi.transfer(0b110);
spi.transfer(addr << 1);
data = spi.transfer(0);
```

That will give 5-bit zero, start-bit, op-code in the first transfer, and followed by 7-bit address and dummy bit (LSB) in second transfer. The third transfer is the read data.

EWEN would map to:

```
spi.transfer(0b1001);
spi.transfer(0b10000000);
```

EWEN has op-code(00), followed by 9-bits, 0b11XXXXXXX.

The WRITE operation becomes:

```
spi.transfer(0b10);
spi.transfer(0x80 | addr);
spi.transfer(data);
```

Cheers!

Comment: I updated my .ino file per your suggestion: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5f29911c6f1c15d0660f

But now I get even stranger results, by writing 0 to all bits the output is '10000000' for the first half of the words and '11111111' for the second half.

What is your reasoning behind doing address & 0x7f?

Comment: There is much more to consider with the other commands. In any case, the READ command has to create the sequence S(1), OP(10), ADDR(7-bit). The LSB of OP is MSB of the 8-bit with address therefore addr & 0x7f (alternatively alway keep address less than 128). The was a way to explain where the LSB of OP was.

Comment: You need to verify all other sequences and then there is a special dummy bit in READ response that needs some consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

I adjusted my code one final time and added some comments:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e085bd2d639f137d1a3
It might be useful for other in the future.

Comment: You are welcome. I had a look. Here are some possible changes (and tests). line 88-91: Could rewrite this as "data1 = (data1 << 1) | (data2 != 0);". line 82-85: Could you test this: "SPI.transfer(0b110); SPI.transfer(address << 1);  data1 = SPI.transfer(0); "

Comment: That works!
The replacement for lines 82-85 is pretty awesome good thinking! No need for the data2 now. Thanks again!

Comment: Updated the answer above with this finding.